# What wrong with my json encode?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to make JSON data response with PHP
So what wrong with my data code?

My Code

```
$data = array(
            'data' => null,
            'status',
            'code' => 1005
        );
```

Output

```
"data":null,"0":"status","code":1005}
```

This is what i need in Output

```
{
    "data": null,
    "status": {
        "code": "1005",
        "message": "Insufficient Balance",
        "datetime": "2018-03-02T01:46:19-04:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: This code looks incomplete and badly formatted.

Comment: Hi Everyone, Sorry for that I edited.

Comment: Notice how the `status` line is different from everything else in the input? Maybe that's why the output is not what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it written, `status` is a *value*. You need to use it as a *key* instead to get the result you want.

```
<?php
$data = array(
            'data' => null,
            'status' => ['code' => 1005]
        );
```

The `0` is there in the result you're seeing because PHP automatically creates numeric indexes (starting with zero) when you assign values to arrays without specifying their keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your array like this:

```
$data = array(
    'data' => null,
    'status' => [
        'code' => 1005,
        'message' => 'Insufficient Balance',
        'datetime' => '2018-03-02T01:46:19-04:00'

    ]
);
```

You can convert this to `JSON` with the following:

```
$json = json_encode($data);
```